# Copycat Operator (Minor spoiler)

Tags: prey

In my fifth playthrough, for the first time, I found a "Copycat Operator":

> [image]

Instead of requiring level 4 Hacking to hack, it only required level 2.

Is there a purpose to it? I was in a panic, so I quickly used Combat mode and hacked every operator in the room, so I wasn't able to tell if it would have tried to attack me or not.

This was in the Trauma Center during the

> Luther Glass ambush

Comment: Just a guess its the one that made the call to start said quest.

Comment: @Madcow That's very possible.